# Pass string variable to db helper and use in query

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, get

I have created two string variables, 'questionString' and 'answerSetId' - the first of which I have assigned to a textview - the second of which I would like to pass to my db helper class:

```
    public void showNextRandomQuestion3() {

        SQLDatabaseHelper db = new SQLDatabaseHelper(this);

        //get the data from the database
        List<List<String>> listList = db.getAllAnswersByQuestion1();

        //Get the question/text/answer Strings
        List<String> questionStrings = listList.get(0); //question Strings
        List<String> answerSetIds = listList.get(4);

        //Generate random index
        Random r = new Random();
        int rand = Math.abs((r.nextInt() % questionStrings.size()));

        //get answer description for randomly selected question
        String questionString = questionStrings.get(rand);  
        String answerSetId = answerSetIds.get(rand); 

        questionView.setText(questionString);

        }
```

In my db helper class, I want to use this string variable as pat of my query:

```
public List<List<String>> getAnswers() {

    List<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();    
    List<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();  

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ANSWERS + "WHERE " + ASID
            + " = " + ??answerSetId??;

   Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
   if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {

     String textdescr = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TDESCR));
     String answersdescr = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ADESCR));
     array1.add(textdescr);
     array2.add(answersdescr);;

    } while (c.moveToNext());

 }
   List< List<String> > listArray2 = new ArrayList< List<String> >();
   listArray2.add(array1);
   listArray2.add(array2);

   return listArray2;
}
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to perform a SELECT, you can use [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
```

instead of raw query. In your case:

```
String selection = ASID+"=?";
String selectionArgs[] = new String[]{String.valueOf(answerSetId)};
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_ANSWERS, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

You can also select some specific columns, passing a list of columns name as second parameter (insted of null). Also, you can replace the last three null value in the example for adding the `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

For example, in your query you are interested only in the two columns TDESCR and ADESCR. So you could use this query:

```
String[] columns = new String[]{TDESCR, ADESCR};
String selection = ASID+"=?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(answerSetId)};
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_ANSWERS, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

There are a lot of others override methods query. Take a look at the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

However, if you prefer you can perform a raw query in this way:

```
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ANSWERS +
    " WHERE "+ASID+"=?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(answerSetId)};
sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(queryString, selectionArgs);
```

Comment: Excellent - thanks. For the first part of my question - How do I pass 'answerSetId' from main activity to db helper?

Comment: simply modifing your method `getAnswers(String answerSetId)`

Comment: Thanks again - Probably asking the absolute obvious, but what would I need to add to my main activity method 'showNextRandomQuestion3() ' to pass the 'answerSetId' over.

Comment: I suppose that your db helper is extending `SQLiteOpenHelper`, so you can declare the metod `showNextRandomQuestion3()` as static, and call it from your main activity in this way: `DbHelper.showNextRandomQuestion3()`. However consider that a more clear and modular way of manage it, it's using a DAO class, that incapsulate all the methods you require for accessing your database. Look at [this example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) , you can see the DAO class named as `CommentsDataSource`

Comment: Am just trying TO play around using you last comment basically. db helper is extending 'SQLiteOpenHelper' as you suggest. When I set the 'showNextRandomQuestion3()' method as static, I have to set the 'questionView' modifier to static also and cannot use 'this' in a static context. Just trying to still work out what my ''showNextRandomQuestion3' would look like basically - plus I haven't returned anything for the 'answerSetId' in that method yet which is what I was wondering what I need to add to do that.

Comment: You have definitely helped though - so I do accept this. May be I have a more specific question in the not too distant future. Cheers. Much appreciated